# onClick trigger server side function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm trying to call a server-side function from the client but I am being thrown a 404 error. What's going wrong? The code looks right to me and I've double checked all syntax.

Server-side JS

```
app.post('/verify', function (req, res) {
  console.log('oh hey');
});
```

Client-side JS

```
$('#verify').click(function() {
  $.post('/verify');
});
```

Jade

```
input#verify(name='verify', value='verify', type='submit')
```

Error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/verify 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: do you see the console.log('oh hey')? I guess if you don't call res.send(...) the next route handler gets called (which finally returns 404)

Comment: Are you sure `/verify` is at the root of your server ? Do you have url rewriting going on at some point ?

Comment: do the other apis, ie: get, work, but only this post api not working?

Answer (score 0):

The client does not get any response. You are only console.logging in your route handler

Try sending a response:

```
app.post('/verify', function (req, res) {
  console.log('oh hey');
  return res.send('hello, world');
});
```

And it should work :)

Comment: No luck unfortunately. I don't even make it to the console.log
Any other ideas?